# Laravel 'BelongsToMany' relations always return value in its 'updated' key (even if the record hasn't changed)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have many-to-many relation between `project_media` & `tag` pivot table `project_media_tag`. *It has additional field `qty`.*

I'm doing a `syncWithoutDetaching` to attach any new / update already existing records *(its additional field)*. But it gives

```
Array
(
    [syncResult] => Array
        (
            [attached] => Array
                (
                )

            [detached] => Array
                (
                )

            [updated] => Array 
                (
                    [0] => 92 // tag_id
                    [1] => 93
                )

        )
)
```

Even though I have these tags (92,93) in my pivot with exactly same value in additional field `qty`.

---

### **QUESTION: I'm under the impression that it should only return values in `updated` key if anything in my pivot table is changed like `qty`, Should it ?**

```
class ProjectMedia extends Model
{

    public function syncTags(){

        // ...
        $projectMedia = self::firstOrNew(['id' => $item['id']],$update);
        
        // ...

        $projectMedia->save(); // Creating & Updating Both

        $syncResult = $projectMedia->btm_Tags()->syncWithoutDetaching($requestedPmTags);
        
        // ... output $syncResult
    }


    // Relationship
    public function btm_Tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Tag",'project_media_tag','target_id',
                                    'tag_id','id','id')->withPivot('qty')
            ->withTimestamps()->using('App\Models\ProjectMediaTag');
    }
}
```

## Schemas

**project_media**

| id | project_id | target_id | target_type | path | note | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at | media_type | ref_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**project_media_tag**

| target_id | target_type | tag_id | qty | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**tag**

| id | company_id | ref_id | ref_type | name | order_by | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at | target_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution of this specific issue is [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19326).

It says you have to remove `withTimestamps()`, removing it **DOES** fix the issue.

Only when `qty`'s value is changed, the `updated` key is returned with value (tag_id related model ids) indicating a value has been changed. But, not exactly what I was looking for since **I need those timestamps**.